# Recompute Angular Directives on View Change?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a div with elements that rely on `ng-class` to set a few style properties (it calls a function that returns a string of classes). Usually when something in the div is modified, Angular will recompute all the `ng-class` variables for me. However, I have a button outside this div that simply adds a class to it to change its width; when this happens, Angular doesn't recompute the `ng-class` functions. Only after I do some action inside that div does it compute everything for me. Is there any way I can force Angular to recompute after pressing this external button?

Comment: You probably want to read [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/watch-digest-apply.html) or [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/) if you want to learn and understand what's happening. If not, just do a `$scope.$digest()` after pressing that button.

Comment: It looks like your button doesn't fire a digest. Does it button use ngClick or a jQuery event to add the class?

Answer (score 0):

Might work if you pass your data in to the directive

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    
  
  
})
.directive('testDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      classData: '='
    },
    template: '<div ng-class="classData"> My directive </div>'
  };
});
```

```css
.blue {
background: blue;
}
.green {
background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <test-directive class-data="myClass"></test-directive>
  
  <input type="text" ng-model="myClass" />(green or blue)

</div>
```